# plotly: not showing error when wrong data passed

Tags: plotly

I am just experimenting with plotly

df is a pandas dataframe with 10 columns

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df[df.columns[0:4]],
        y=df[df.columns[0]],
        name="V1 Mag",
    ))

fig.show()
```

Here if i pass 4 columns (0,1,2,3) data to xaxis its accepting as x-axis without showing any error.

```
        x=df[df.columns[0:4]],
        y=df[df.columns[0]],
```

I am expecting that plotly should accpet only single array of data for each axis, else show error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it's a stylistic thing: some libraries are more strict and will throw an error, but others will simply have unexpected behavior if you don't use methods or parameters as intended. In this case, passing an array instead of a vector for the x coordinates will cause Plotly to try to best interpret what you meant.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 10)))

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df[df.columns[0:4]],
        y=df[df.columns[0]],
        name="V1 Mag",
    ))

fig.show()
```

[image]

And the DataFrame looks like this:

[image]

It looks like if you pass an `m x n` array where m > 1, Plotly will try to interpret the first two rows of the DataFrame as a category. In general, you will find that working with Plotly, it's a very flexible library, so it doesn't "break" that often, but it won't work as intended if you do something ambiguous like you're doing here.

Comment: `Plotly will try to interpret the first two rows of the DataFrame as a category. ` What is category

Comment: Categorical data. The first x value is [51, 87], the second x value is [92, 99], and so on... these numbers don't have any meaning in terms of where they are placed on the plot. If you changed the values in the array you are passing to x, but kept y the same, the plot would look exactly the same but with different x listed on the x-axis.